# Firebase storage : list files in a specific directory

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

How to list files in Firebase storage in a specific directory (eg: /test),

**Here is what I tried :**

```
 var query = {
    delimiter: 'test/'
};

const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket().getFiles(query, function(err, files, nextQuery, apiResponse) {

  console.log(files);
}
```

but it returns files at the root of the bucket..

Any idea?

Comment: Check think link: 'https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js'. some useful examples there. first, bucket is storage bucket and files inside that bucket so getFiles() there put all the nested folder path and you got list of resources inside that folder.

Comment: @phonemyatt any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797054/firebase-cloud-function-problem-with-promise-allpromise ?

Comment: Is there a way to get a specific file in Storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're not passing the correct object to getFiles().  The documentation for the [GetFilesRequest](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/global#GetFilesRequest) object suggests that you should be passing a property called `directory`, not `delimiter`.  If you want all the files under `/test`, then pass `{ directory: '/test' }`