# Firebase cloud function: problem with Promise.all(promise)

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I loop throw a list of files in Firebase storage and I would like to modify a string while looping,

**Here is what I tried to do:**

```
 var str;

 storage.bucket().file(...).download((err, content) => {
    str=content.toString();

    storage.bucket().getFiles(...).then(results => {
        const files = results[0];
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
           files.forEach(file => {
               ...
               str=str.replace("t","a");
           });
           resolve(str);
      });

      Promise.all(promise).then(function(str) {
        console.log(str); //NOT OKAY, the value is still "test" 

        file.save(str, function(err) { ... });
     });
```

I tried also :

> promise.then(function(result) {

but it's the same result:(

**UPDATE :**
I edited the code above but it still doesn't work :

[image]

Any idea?

**UPDATE 2 :**

[image]

it still doesn't work:(

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code in its entirety.  The way you're showing it now, there's no guarantee that the promise you create in the first block of code is the same as the promise you pass to Promise.all().  It could be out of scope.

Comment: Don't use `forEach` if you are doing something asynchronous inside. If you are not doing something asynchronous, do not use a promise.

Comment: Why are you using `Promise.all`? You don't have multiple promises, do you?

Comment: Your `promise` variable is created inside the `then` callback, you cannot use it outside. But `then` already creates a promise for the return value of the callback, just use that!

Comment: @Bergi so what to use instead of Promise.all ? or how to do without forEach? I'm a bit lost..

Comment: @Bergi it still doesn't work, indeed there is another line above and I don't know how should be the promise, I updated the question with a screenshot of the code, any idea?

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the question with the entirely code, any idea?

Comment: @Julien Better put code as text, not paintings.

Comment: @Julien Looks like you need to `return` the promise from the outer `then` callback. Also it's really weird that `.download()` both takes a callback and returns a promise.

Comment: @Bergi I think you're right, download() doesn't return a promise, how to do then?

Comment: Wrap it in a `new Promise` so that you get a promise for the result. But wrap only the `download(…)` call, nothing else! See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for details

Comment: @Bergi I tried but it still doesn't work:( I updated the question with what I tried..

Comment: Don't forget to call `reject` when there's an `err`, but otherwise this looks fine. What doesn't work?

Comment: @Bergi now the cloud functions suddently doesn't return any error, but "result" in the promise.then doesn"t have the value modified by str.replace

Comment: @Bergi that goes directly to the promise.then and result is "undefined"

Comment: @Julien If my answer helped, you might want to upvote it.

Comment: @Bergi any idea Bergi about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881350/flutter-retrieve-firebase-key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can be usefull for someone, here is the solution I found:

```
var promises = [];
var str="string containing data to replace with signed url";

storage.bucket().getFiles({ prefix: folderPath }).then(results => {
  const files = results[0];
  files.forEach(function(file) {

     promises.push( //the trick was here

       file.getSignedUrl(signedUrlConfig).then(signedUrls => {
         ...
         surl = signedUrls[0];
         str=str.replace("a",surl); //eg: replace with signed url.
         return str;
       });
     );
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log(str); //str contains all signed url
  });
});
```

Comment: WTH? You had no `file.getSignedUrl(signedUrlConfig)` promise call in the code in your question, there was no way we could have come up with this solution.

Comment: I wrote "that goes directly to the promise.then and result is "undefined": that could only means that sthg didn't have time to be executed before, so we could guess there was sthg asynchronous even if the async code was not written, and that's how I comed up with the solution.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for

```
const promise = storage.bucket().file().download().then(str => {
//    ^^^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^
    return storage.bucket().getFiles().then(results => {
//  ^^^^^^
        const files = results[0];
        for (const file of files) {
            …
            str = str.replace("t","a");
        }
        return str;
    //  ^^^^^^
    });
});

promise.then(str => { /*
^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
    console.log(str);
    return file.save(str); // should return a promise
});
```

You need neither `new Promise` nor `Promise.all` here. You might use the latter though to remove the nesting and potentially even run `getFiles()` and `download()` concurrently, see [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572).

Comment: async/await is often a pleasant choice as well. Node 8 runtime is required (and supported) for Firebase Functions.  Promise.all best though for parallel operation.